# io.fabric.k8s client : pod phase is showing as "Running" even when some of the containers are not in READY state

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm using Java Fabric k8s client to get List of the PODs where phase is equal to  "Running".
I have 2 containers in the POD. What I noticed is getPods() method is returning POD as Running even one of the 2 containers is still not in READY state.

Why is this happening when all the containers in the pod are not in READY state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Running` is a Pod *status* state that is defined as:

> "The Pod has been bound to a node, and all of the containers have been created. At least one container is still running, or is in the process of starting or restarting."

Just one of the Pod's containers needs to be booting up or running to sufficiently mark the whole Pod as `Running`. Possible states are `Pending, Running, Succeeded, Failed, Unknown`. Think of these as the highest-level description of the Pod state. Each of these states has a Pod *condition* array amongst other metadata that provide more details about the containers inside.

`Ready` is a Pod *condition* which is a sub-state of a Pod `status` (`status.condition`). In simplest terms, when a Pod is marked as `Ready`, it's fully booted up and able to accept *traffic*. Sometimes this does depend on how your Pod spec is set up; for example, if your Pod has a `readinessProbe`, it reaches `Ready` only if the `readinessProbe` succeeds.

Example: `kubectl get po`

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nani-play-8b6b89455-9g674   1/1     Running   0          13s
```

If I explore deeper into the pod via `kubectl describe po nani-play-8b6b89455-9g674`, amongst the other information is

```
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True     <---- 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True
```

Comment: Even though your explanation is correct, My issue is specifically with fabric8 client.

Comment: I'm using pod.status.containerStatuses.stream().allMathch(ContainerStatus::getReady) .. It still returns the pod even when all of containers are not ready